# Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= ,

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

```
DECLARE @Recaudacion as INT
DECLARE @Division as INT

SELECT @Recaudacion = (SELECT SUM(pelicula.PrecioEntrada) 
                       FROM pelicula) 

SELECT @Division = (SELECT COUNT(*) 
                    FROM funcion  
                    GROUP BY NombrePelicula 
                    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1)

SELECT 
    (@Recaudacion / @Division) AS Recaudacion, 
    funcion.NombrePelicula 
FROM funcion
```

I get this message

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

I'm expecting the average price for each show

Comment: When you dumped your error message into your favourite search engine, what was wrong with the [about 9310 results](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22Subquery+returned+more+than+1+value.+This+is+not+permitted+when+the+subquery+follows+%3D%2C+%21%3D%2C+%3C%2C+%3C%3D+%2C+%3E%2C+%3E%3D%22)? What about them didn't you understand? What about the error, which is *explicitly* telling you the problem, don't you underrstand?

Comment: COUNT / GROUP BY / HAVING [can return more than one row](https://dbfiddle.uk/-Tr6dABs).

Comment: You know SQL Server 2008 has been fully end of life since 2019, right? That means is hasn't received any patches -- **not even critical security updates** -- for several years now. It's dangerous and irresponsible to continue using it. Upgrading to a supported release is job #1 here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see this in a comment:

> i need more than one value

Okay. Let's run this as a real query then:

```
SELECT NombrePelicula, 
    (SELECT SUM(pelicula.PrecioEntrada) FROM pelicula) / count(*) As Recaudacion
FROM funcion  
GROUP BY NombrePelicula 
HAVING COUNT(*)>1
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT count(*) FROM funcion GROUP BY NombrePelicula
```

Will return the `count` for each `NombrePelicula` so it can be more than one value.

You could try:

```
DECLARE @Recaudacion As integer = (SELECT SUM(pelicula.PrecioEntrada) FROM pelicula) 
SELECT @Recaudacion / count(*) as Recaudacion, NombrePelicula 
FROM funcion  
GROUP BY NombrePelicula 
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Comment: Yes, but i need more than one value so how can i solve this? is there some way to do it?

Comment: @MateGraviFiorino Please read [how to MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @MateGraviFiorino If you need more than one value, you need more than one variable. `@Division` is just one integer. You can't assign a whole set of values to it.